# How to copy data from one field to another field in different row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Newbie here, and SQL Server novice: I have a SQL Server 2008 database, and would like to copy the value of a specific field to another field in a different record. Here's what I've found so far, but produces error. The solution was provided here, but I believe not valid for for SQL Server:

- `products` = table
- `related1-5` are columns that I want to copy
- sku criteria defines from which record and to which record I would like to copy

Code:

```
UPDATE products t1, products t2
SET t2.related1 = t1.related1
SET t2.related2 = t1.related2
SET t2.related3 = t1.related3
SET t2.related4 = t1.related4
SET t2.related5 = t1.related5
WHERE t2.sku = '4056c'
AND t1.sku = '4056b'
```

Comment: in other words you want the content of row t2.sku = '4056c' to replace / update the content of row t1.sku = '4056b'? Or viceversa?

Comment: also, can you also share with us the structure of table products ? It would be helpful.

Comment: Eduard Uta - thanks for reply...sorry was not watching yesterday. I want to copy from content of row t1.sku = '4056b' to '4056c'.

RE structure of table - not sure what/how do I find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the fancyest way but this is a way to do it:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.related1 = (select related1 from products where sku = '4056b'),
    t.related2 = (select related2 from products where sku = '4056b'),
    t.related3 = (select related3 from products where sku = '4056b'),
    t.related4 = (select related4 from products where sku = '4056b'),
    t.related5 = (select related5 from products where sku = '4056b')
FROM products t
WHERE t.sku = '4056c'
```

Comment: If for some reason there are duplicate rows you may want to update the subqueries to something like "(select related1 from products where sku = '4056b' group by related1)" ... and so on (so add group by to each one).

Comment: this worked, copy/pasted as provided, without grouping! AWESOME. I feel so empowered. Thank YOU! Now I need to learn more about how to use this formum... eric bernhard

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your `UPDATE` a bit:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
       related1, related2, related3, related4, related5
    FROM
       dbo.Products
    WHERE
       sku = '4056b'
)
UPDATE dbo.Products
SET related1 = CTE.related1,
    related2 = CTE.related2,
    related3 = CTE.related3,
    related4 = CTE.related4,
    related5 = CTE.related5
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    sku = '4056c'
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but in order for the join and where clauses to find a match the two rows should be joined on a column where both rows have the same value on that column (so the column should be a "grouping" column with duplicate rows and definitely not a PK).

Comment: an idea to overcome this would be to use a CTE for the update (join next CTE with actual table on sku), and in the CTE having "inside" a select related1, related2... , '4056c' as sku from products where sku = '4056b' .

Comment: @EduardUta: OK, changed it to be a CTE that first selects the source columns from your table, and then applies them to the `Products` table for the second `sku` value.